# How to install ROS on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS on a RPi 3 to use it to train middle school students in single arm industrial robotics.

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
> PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8
> (jessie)" NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
> VERSION_ID="8" VERSION="8 (jessie)"

In order to use apt-get install for ROS I used instructions in the ROS wiki to modify my apt sources list. My ros-latest.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d reads

> deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main contrib non-free

but I get the following error when I run sudo apt-get update

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
```

I suspect that I am doing something wrong with the $(lsb_release -sc) part of the ros-latest.list file.

Any ideas? I also plan to install Gazebo the same way if I can get ROS installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261001/how-to-install-ros-on-a-raspberry-pi?/) by [bstanard](https://answers.ros.org/users/30253/bstanard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First I would advise to use Ubuntu Mate 16.04 rather than Raspbian.

If you use Raspbian there are no binaries available for you to install ROS directly (see [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation), there is no `armhf` build for Debian); you have to compile all the ROS packages you need to get things running; this might take a considerable amount of time, it is a tedious/complicated process.

Also note that there is a bug in RViz preventing to visualize STL files on ARM architecture: [RViz bug report](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/850)

### Install from binaries (Ubuntu MATE)

If you use Ubuntu MATE 16.04 you will be able to install ROS following the standard procedure because binaries for the ARM hard float (`armhf`) hardware architecture are available.

One major drawback with Ubuntu MATE is that hardware acceleration is not enabled, 3D graphics (RViz) will be very slow! These information are summarized [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1088).

[You can get Ubuntu MATE 16.04.2 here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/)

To install ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 with your Raspberry Pi 3 just follow [the standard instructions for Ubuntu](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu).

### Compile / install from source

[Instructions are here.](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source)

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3